# Acquia Drush Access

Tags: drush, ssh

We are hosting a couple of sites on Acquia Cloud.  Up to now I have SSH into the servers when I needed to execute any drush commands, but I want to start using drush on my local dev machine to execute commands on the servers.

Some of the commands work without an problems `drush ac-site-list`, but as soon as a SSH key is required (for example `drush @site.env status` I get a `Permission denied (publickey).` error message.  I know this means that the public SSH key being used is not valid, and I also know why this is happening.  I have only one SSH key for all the Acquia servers, but because there are different servers for the different sites, and in addition to that I have a couple of 'personal or private' key's; SSH does not know which key to use when I execute Drush.

For other SSH access (SSH in generate to other servers), I use a config file in my .ssh folder with aliases.

The problem is that I do not know how to tell Drush which 'ssh alias' from the .ssh/config file to use.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: It depends a bit on the structure of the alias file Acquia provides, and it would be helpful if you could update your question with the structure of it.

Answer (score 3):

The Drush alias file has an option to provide additional parameters:

> 'ssh-options': If the target requires special options, such as a non- standard port, alternative identity file, or alternative 
>   authentication method, ssh-options can contain a string of extra
>   options that are used with the ssh command, eg "-p 100"

Source: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php

To have SSH use the right SSH key you can append it with `ssh -i path/to/key.pem user@server`. So in your alias file you should be able to add:

```
$aliases['alias'] = array(
  ...
  'ssh-options' => '-i path/to/key.pem',
  ...
);
```

I am not sure if you can use the keys defined in `.ssh/config`, because the config file automatically connects the SSH key with the host. So you'd be able to call `ssh user@server` and SSH should append the key. Therefore I doubt it can be used as I'd assume drush will automatically use `remote-host` and `remote-user` to build the SSH connection: `ssh remote-user@remote-host` and the keys from `.ssh/config` shoud be applied at that point.

Comment: perfect.  Added the ssh-options key to each of the alias arrays and it worked.  Thanks